How to renew IP address with Ubuntu 24.04?
I used to use the following commands in order to release and renew the IP address:
dhclient -r    
dhclient eth0

But dhclient is not installed on Ubuntu 24.04.
I could probably just install it, but maybe there is another command that come instead of dhclient in the new release?

This question is similar to: How do I renew my DHCP lease?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There are a few non-dhclient answers there

With no dhclient and dhcpcd in 24.04 by default, using nmcli seems to be the way forward.
This following command works and renewed the lease:
nmcli connection down <interface_name> && nmcli connection up <interface_name>

Another option:
nmcli connection modify <connection_name> ipv4.dhcp-timeout 1 && nmcli device reapply <interface_name>

To find <connection_name>: nmcli connection show
To list <interface_name>: nmcli device status

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Just built a new 24.04.1 Server and found it lacking nmcli. So perhaps there is a difference between Server and Desktop versions? systemd-networkd worked for me on my server on 24.04.1 as per answer from lkdjofwdf

@SgtMajor  In Ubuntu 24.04.1 Desktop, nmcli is included.

24.04 has moved to a using dhcpcd5 for a DHCP client.
Try "dhcpcd -k" to release the current lease and "dhcpcd eth0" to get a new one.

"dhcpcd is not running" (and yet I have an IP address and DHCP lease), so there must be some other service. Before the upgrade I could use dhclient to renew.

You have to specify the interface after the -k.  eg: "dhcpcd -k ens160" then "dhcpcd ens160" would release and renew the IP address on interface ens160.

As simon said, in a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04, dhcpcd isn't installed or running. It seems that networkctl renew is the right method, as lkdjofwdf said.

networkctl renew eth0
Ubuntu 24.04 uses systemd-networkd
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/networkctl.html

Only Ubuntu Server does, but Ubuntu desktop uses NetworkManager.
